# Finding the number of times a statement runs

Tags: math, analysis

I am told to figure out the number of times the statement `foo` runs in the following program. We are assuming that `n` is an even number.

```
j = 1;
while( j <= n/2 ) 
{
  i = 1;
  while( i <= j ) 
  {
    foo;
    i++;
  }
  j++;
}
```

I figured the best way to go about this would be start from the inner loop and work my way outward. We know that `i = 1` and inside the inner loop we have `i <= j`. That means this inner loop runs `j` times. (This is where I start to get confused) In the outer loop, we see the statement `j <= n/2` so that means this outer loop runs `n/2` times, right? to count the number of times `foo` runs, it would be `j` times `n/2`, wouldn't it? So `foo` runs `j * (n / 2)` times? Is this correct?

Comment: Well, `j` is set, so your  result should be a function of `n` only.

Comment: Work through it for various valued of n (starting with 2) and see if you can determine the pattern.  Hint:  have you ever been bowling?

Comment: Okay I am trying to walk through it starting with 2. When `n = 2` then that means the statement `j <= n/2` is checking to see if `j <= 1` which is true since `j` is initialized to `1`. Then we come to the inner loop and see if `i <= j` which is `true` since both `i` and `j` are `1`. So then `foo` runs once and then `i` is incremented. Now, `i = 2` and we check to see if `i <= j` which is `false` now and we exit that loop and `j` is incremented. Then we go back up to the top to see if `j <= n/2` which is now `false` and the loop exits. So when the program is 2, it runs once.

Comment: Let me try the even number `4`. So `n = 4`, then the loop is checking `j <= 2` which is `true` since `j = 1`. So now we go to the inner loop and test that value and see that its true, so `foo` runs once and now `i = 2`. Now this conditional is false and we exit that loop and `j` is incremented so now `j = 2`. Looking back at the top we test again to see if `j <= 2` which is STILL true, so we go to the inner loop again. `i = 1` and we see if `i <= j` which is true since `i = 1` and `j = 2` so `foo` runs for a second time. Now, `i` is incremented and we have `i = 2` which means that the loop

Comment: will still be `true` and `foo` will run for a third time. After this though, both loops will terminate. So is the pattern to this that the number of times `foo` runs is `n - 1`?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the outer loop runs `N/2` times (`j` increments from 1 to n/2).  The *inner* loop runs `j` times, so the number of times that `foo` runs changes with each incremental values of `j`.  If you count the runs, with each "row" being an outer lopo run, the end result looks like a triangle (or bowling pins if center-justified):

```
N=2

 j
---
 1  .   = one run

N=4

 j
---
 1  .   
 2  ..  = three runs

N=6

 j
---
 1 .
 2 ..
 3 ...  = 6 runs
```

The next step for you is to write the result as a function of `N`.

Comment: So if `n = 8` then j will equal `1, 2, 3 and 4` which means `foo` will run `10` times. For `n = 10`, `foo` will run `15` times, etc. I think I see a pattern. `foo` will run however many times it ran for the PREVIOUS value plus half of `n`. So for example, `n = 8`. The previous amount of runs for foo was when `n = 6` which was `6 runs` so `6 runs` + half of 8 which is `4` which totals `10`. For `n = 10`, there are `10` previous runs and half of current `n` is `5` so `foo` runs 15 times. I'm just having a hard time writing this as a function of just `n`.

Comment: So I see that each time we are adding `n/2`. i.e., when `n = 2` we add `1` run, when `n = 4` we add `2` runs, when `n = 6` we add `3` runs, etc.

Comment: I am completely stumped. I have been looking at this for hours unable to come up with something in terms of just `n`. Can you explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

As we can see *j* increments by 1 till n/2, while for every iteration inner while loop runs *j* times, increment *i* by 1 to 1-*j*.

And for every iteration of inner while `foo` runs 1 time.

For first iteration first iteration *j* = 1, `foo` runs 1 time..

For second *j*=2, `foo` runs 2 times...
For n/2nd iteration *j* = n/2, `foo` runs n/2 times..

So `foo` runs total of 
*1+2+3+...+ n/2* times
That is  n/2 * ((n/2 +1))/2 = n/4 * (n/2 +1) = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
  i = 1;
  while( i <= j ) 
  {
    foo;
    i++;
  }
```

executes `foo` `j` times, so we can replace it with:

```
  NumberOfTimes += j;
```

And the whole code becomes:

```
NumberOfTimes = 0;
j = 1;
while( j <= n/2 ) 
{
  NumberOfTimes += j;
  j++;
}
```

That loop executes its body with `j` equal to 1, then 2, then 3, then 4, and so on until (and including) `j` = *n*/2.

So, at the end, `NumberOfTimes` = 1 + 2 + 3 + … + *n*/2.

There are *n*/2 terms in that sum. The average of the first (1) and last (*n*/2) is (1+*n*/2)/2. The average of the second (2) and second-to-last (*n*/2−1) is (2+*n*/2−1)/2, which equals (1+*n*/2)/2. The average of the third and third-from-last terms is also (1+*n*/2)/2. In fact, we can pair up all the terms in the sum into pairs with average (1+*n*/2)/2, except that, if *n*/2 is odd, there will be a sole term left in the middle. But the middle term will be (1+*n*/2)/2, so its average is also (1+*n*/2)/2.

That means the average of all the terms in the sum is (1+*n*/2)/2. The total of the terms equals the average multiplied by the number of terms, so it is (1+*n*/2)/2 • *n*/2 = *n*<sup>2</sup>/8 + *n*/4. You could also write it as (*n*<sup>2</sup>+2*n*)/8 or *n*•(*n*+2)/8.

Answer (score -2):

Almost there! You are on the right track, but there is a small mistake in your reasoning.

Let's break it down step by step:

The inner loop runs j times because it starts with i = 1 and runs as long as i <= j.

The outer loop runs n/2 times because it starts with j = 1 and runs as long as j <= n/2 (assuming n is an even number).

Now, to find the total number of times foo runs, you need to multiply the number of times the inner loop runs (j times) with the number of times the outer loop runs (n/2 times). So, the correct calculation would be:

Total number of times foo runs = j * (n / 2)

Since j is a variable in the code and not a fixed value, you cannot determine its specific value without knowing the value of n. However, you can express the total number of times foo runs in terms of n and j as:

Total number of times foo runs = n * (n / 2) / 2

Please note that the actual value of j changes in each iteration of the outer loop, starting from 1 and incrementing by 1 in each iteration until j reaches n/2.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT