# Analyze a given program

Tags: algorithm, math, analysis

I am given a segment of code and told to analyze it. I am so confused. I need to figure out how many times `foo` runs and use that to determine a function of `n`. I know how many times `foo` runs, but I am unable to determine the correct function. Here is the code:

```
j = 1;
while( j <= n/2 )
{
   i = 1;
   while( i <= j )
   {
      foo;
      i++;
   }
   j++;
}
```

I know that `foo` runs in a pattern where half of `n` is added to the runs. So for instance, when `n = 2`, `foo` runs `1` time, when `n = 4`, `foo` runs `3` times, when `n = 6`, `foo` runs `6` times, etc. Something like this:

```
n = 2   runs -> j = 1 *          1 run


n = 4   runs -> j = 1 * 
                j = 2 * *        3 runs

n = 6   runs -> j = 1 * 
                j = 2 * *
                j = 3 * * *      6 runs

n = 8   runs -> j = 1 *
                j = 2 * *
                j = 3 * * *
                j = 4 * * * *    10 runs
```

Maybe I am just over thinking this, but I have been staring at my notebook for hours trying to come up with some function in terms of only `n` that follows this behavior. Can anyone help?

**EDIT** I have another question. How do I know if this function is in Big-O, or Big-Theta? Is it something to do with using a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140945

Comment: "while loop instead of a for loop"? I think you need a primer on complexity. Complexity is only dependent on the number of operations a programs does, not on the actual iterative construct used to accomplish the same. Realise that irrespective of whether you use a for loop or a while loop, the number of operations is same.

Comment: Some of the examples I am looking at that use a `while` loop deal with Big-O since they CAN end early if some condition is met. For instance, `for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)` will run `n` times, but `while(i <= n && !done)` may not run `n` times since we have the condition `... && !done)`. Since it may end early, we are dealing with Big-O since we can end "less than or equal to" `n` times. Where if we have a loop that will execute exactly `n` times, that means Big-Theta. Does that sound right?

Answer (score 1):

Once we realize that the bulk of the work is done by the inner while loop, we can compute the runtime(for a given n) as the number of times the inner while loop runs:

```
1+2+3+...n/2
```

which is by [summation formula](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/groups/tatami/kumo/exs/sum/)

= O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: OP is asking for the _actual_ number of runs, not the big-O order.

Comment: This does include the number of loop executions.  It's the n/2-th triangle number.  Closed form (n/2)((n/2)-1)/2, which is the summation 1+2+3+...+n/2.  And of course this is asymptotically quadratic (dominated by n^2).  If we're being _super_ technical here, it's actually:  floor(n/2)(floor(n/2) - 1)/2 because of the truncation of integer division.  But generally considering such insignificant factors is bad form, hence most people would answer this with O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

*j* runs *n / 2* times. For each such iteration, *i* runs *j*  times. For each such iteration of *i*, `foo` is called. So the number of calls is

*∑<sub>j = 1</sub><sup>n / 2</sup> [j] = (1 + n / 2) n / 4 = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

It's just an [arithmetic series](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/atp2/arithseq.htm) from 1 to *n / 2*.

Comment: OP is asking for the _actual_ number of runs, not the big-O order.

Comment: Thanks, @DStanley - I somehow doubt the end purpose isn't the order of growth, but updated the sum.

Comment: I get that `j` runs `n / 2` times and for each such iteration `i` runs `j` times. I am just confused on how from that, we get `[(1 + n / 2) * n] / 2`. I do see that since we have an `n` times another `n`, the Big-Theta order overall will be $n^2$. How did you know to add `n / 2` to `1` and then multiply that by `n` and divide the quantity by `2`? I was scratching things out for hours.

Comment: I think there might be an error in the function. When `n = 4` for instance, the answer should be `3 runs`. But when I plug in `4` into the equation I keep getting `6`.

Comment: I think the function should be `(1 + n / 2) n / 4`

Comment: @genericuser007 You are absolutely correct - thanks! corrected.